# How can I update a var in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my var depth for example everytime find a new value, I did this but I don't if is the best way to update this var.

```
void Update()
{
    Terrain terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();
    terrain.terrainData = GenerateTerrain(terrain.terrainData);

    offsetX += Time.deltaTime * 1f;

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\----\documents\BrainGrapher\posiciones.txt");
    char[] delimitar = { ':' };
    string s = reader.ReadLine();
    string[] value = s.Split(delimitar);

    while (s != null)
    {
        for (int move = 0; move < value .Length; move ++)
        {
            save= vlues[recorrer];
            Debug.Log(save);
        }
        depth = Convert.ToInt32(save);
        Debug.Log(depth);
        s = reader.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

The idea is to take a value from the file and everytime this value is updated, the var depth is changed and so the graphic changed too, the variable depth is using just here.

```
    TerrainData GenerateTerrain(TerrainData terrainData)
{
    terrainData.heightmapResolution = width + 1;
    terrainData.size = new Vector3(width, depth, height);
    terrainData.SetHeights(0, 0, GenerateHeights());
    return terrainData;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Given that your code is in Spanish, you may want to ask in [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1):

In C#, there is a class called [**FileSystemWatcher**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

This class will allow you to register to an event so you don't have to check yourself by reading the file in each update.

You should create a FileSystemWatcher in the Start method and register to it. Then you only read the depth value if the file has changed, and you don't have to do anything in the update method. You can even check these events

```
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
```

Comment: thanks, a question, the file has an array of values, I need the program to move between the values of the matrix and use the value that belongs to it, with this function can I do that ?, the file if it is updated every "x "time, then it works for that, I'd like if it also works for what I mentioned earlier.